# Flat PVC Cap to fit a 3" PVC pipe

Tags: plumbing, pvc

I'm looking for a flat PVC cap for 3" PVC pipe. I ordered [a few 3" PVC DWV Schedule 30 Caps Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BPS5XS) that were too small.

I've measured the 3" PVC pipe, and it appears the outer diameter is just over 3.5", so the cap's interior will need to be that size.

I've found some in the local hardware stores (Lowes, Home Depot...etc) that fit, but are rounded on the top. I need them to be flat. I know they exist, but can't figure out what they're called, or how to find them for sale anywhere (online or other).

**Question:**

What is the name of this PVC product and how/where can I find them for sale?

[image]

Comment: I've never heard of Schedule 30, but a 3" SCH40 PVC pipe [has an OD](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pvc-cpvc-pipes-dimensions-d_795.html) of 3.5".

Comment: Why do you need them to be flat? Very curious what plumbing situation requires this. I suspect it may be a craft hobby.

Comment: @statueuphemism - it's not for plumbing, it's for a random home DIY "for fun" project where I need it mounted to a flat surface. I know they exist, as I've seen them in use.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I don't see caps on the link you shared. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dave, No, that page was just a reference showing that what you are trying to cap off is probably 3" SCH40 pipe, so what you are looking for is a cap that is made to fit SCH40 pipe, not SCH30.

Comment: FWIW schedule 30 is thin wall (non pressure) drain pipe.  You might convert the whole project.. but you'll have a very hard time finding odd fittings I suppose.

Comment: It's worth checking the yellow pages for your local plumber's supply house; they typically have a broader inventory than hardware stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I just ran across it.  If you are still looking, you might try this:
https://www.pvcfittingsonline.com/3-pvc-flat-cap-furniture-grade.html

Answer (score 1):

I use Female threaded couplings with a flat cleanout plug... a bit of overkill but good and flat

Comment: I need it to not be threaded though.

Answer (score 0):

Flat caps are common with ABS drain fittings. If you can live with black caps (as opposed to white) it should be easy to find one in ABS, which can be glued to PVC using special "universal" glue. The pipe and fittings are the same size.

Comment: That's a good point, but I know the PVC fittings exist, and would prefer them over ABS.